# GNOME classic on Ubuntu 15?

Tags: gnome

If I install an Ubuntu 15.10 (not an older version), how can I set the GNOME classic GUI as default?

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu MATE](http://ubuntu-mate.org/) was created for users who liked the classic gnome 2 style and does an amazing job with some pretty nifty features.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo service lightdm restart
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Now you should be able to choose the Desktop manager you want (Unity or GNOME).
On the next login, GNOME will be default.